# Drag & Drop from Infragistics Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, ribbon

I would like to **darg&drop from Infragistics menu** like a button (in fact any UI element behind it) to the `Grid`.

But It seems is impossible to do.

Normally I do like

```
 <Border Margin="2,0" CornerRadius="5" Name="MyControl1" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"  MouseLeftButtonDown="captureMyControl1_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="captureMyControl1_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="captureMyControl1_MouseMove">
```

And I can drag&drop it because it has appropriate methods.
But it seems like we cannot do this with **Infragistics Ribbon Menu**

and this code

```
<ig:XamRibbonTabItem>
 <ig:XamRibbonGroup>
  <ig:VerticalRibbonToolContainer>
     <Border Margin="2,0" CornerRadius="5" Name="MyControl1" 
          <tools:ButtonToolEx
```

I mean I cannot see that for instance **Ribbon Button** has those methods or we can add `Border` over it.

May be my question might be redefined like this: Can we use standard SIlverlight Controls in Infragistics Menu?
Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally, I found a way to resolve that problem.

I am not gonna put the code because there lots of things but I will reference to this great link

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/39619.aspx

Now imagine that instead of  `private ComboBox _combo;` you can  do like

```
 private MyCUstomUSerControl _myCUstomUSerControl;
```

And this is a way to implement ANY custom user control within **Infragistics Ribbon menu**.

Have a nice day, folk!

```
public class ComboBoxTool : RibbonTool

    {

        protected override RibbonToolBaseControl ResolveToolControl()

        {

            return new ComboBoxToolControl(this);

        }

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }    

    }

    public class ComboBoxToolControl : RibbonToolBaseControl, IRibbonControl

    {

        private ComboBox _combo;

        public ComboBoxToolControl()

        {           

            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ComboBoxToolControl);            

        }

        public ComboBoxToolControl(RibbonToolBase tool) : base(tool)

        {

            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof (ComboBoxToolControl);

        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()

        {

            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            this._combo = GetTemplateChild("Combo") as ComboBox;

            if (this._combo != null)

                this._combo.ItemsSource = ((ComboBoxTool) this.Tool).ItemsSource;

        }

    }

Then you need to define the style for the ComboBoxToolControl in your generic.xaml file:



<Style TargetType="cust:ComboBoxToolControl">

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="cust:ComboBoxToolControl">

                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">

                        <Grid >

                            <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" Width="100" Height="24" />

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

    </Style>





At this point you should be able to add your combo box tool to the ribbon:



<igr:XamWebRibbonTabItem>

                    <igr:XamWebRibbonGroup>

                        <cust:ComboBoxTool ItemsSource="{StaticResource inventory}">                       

                      </cust:ComboBoxTool>

                    </igr:XamWebRibbonGroup>                  

 </igr:XamWebRibbonTabItem>
```

P.S. And have a look at this link as well http://www.infragistics.com/samples/wpf/ribbon/custom-tools